# Game can't recognize enemy rectangle inside platform rectangle

Tags: c#, xna

So I tried to make it so; if the enemies left side position is more than the platforms right side, the enemy turns to the other way, and vice versa. The problem now is that the game suddenly can't recognize it. This enemy jumps in the air at the same time, so I made it only check the X values. (Right and left sides of the rectangles)
Here is the code:
These checks if it's inside of the platform...

```
static class RectangleHelper
{
    public static bool isInsideOf(this Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    {
        return (r1.Right >= r2.Left &&
            r1.Left <= r2.Right);
    }
}
if (!chompBall.rectangle.isInsideOf(platform.rectangle))
{
    if (chompBall.movingRight == true && chompBall.canChangeDirection == true)
        chompBall.movingRight = false;
    else if (chompBall.movingRight == false && chompBall.canChangeDirection == true)
        chompBall.movingRight = true;
    chompBall.canChangeDirection = false;
}
```

I have tried to change a lot of things, even removed the ! to see if it worked, but no. I have no idea! The funny thing is that it works when it's always touching the ground(my other enemies), but now that only the X coordinate matters, it doesn't.
Please help!
-Edit:
Split the logic? Does that mean doing this?:

```
            if (!chompBall.rectangle.isInsideOf(platform.rectangle) && chompBall.movingRight == true)
                chompBall.movingRight = false;
            else if (!chompBall.rectangle.isInsideOf(platform.rectangle) && chompBall.movingRight == false)
                chompBall.movingRight = true;
```

-Edit 2:
Oh I think I know what you mean. I make on RectangleHelper which checks if it's to the right, and vice versa. It still doesn't work, the result is the same:

```
            if (chompBall.rectangle.isRightOf(platform.rectangle) && chompBall.movingRight == true)
                chompBall.movingRight = false;
            else if (chompBall.rectangle.isLeftOf(platform.rectangle) && chompBall.movingRight == false)
                chompBall.movingRight = true;
```

Edit 3, Enemy Movements. As you can see, here the "canChangeDirection bool is used. It's ment to do; when the enemy reached the end of the platforms, it turns and can't turn again until 100ms. This is used so it doesn't get stuck at the corner:

```
            if (movingRight == true)
            {
                position.X += 2;
                rotation += 0.05f;
            }
            else if (movingRight == false)
            {
                position.X -= 2;
                rotation -= 0.05f;
            }

            if (canChangeDirection == false)
            {
                timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
                if (timer >= 100)
                {
                    canChangeDirection = true;
                    timer = 0;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I wouldn't combine both logic together. I would have: If on the right side and going right Then turn left. If on the left side and going left Then turn right.

Comment: That makes them turn forever, so they look left and then right with no interval, while jumping in the same place :/

Comment: What @the_lotus is saying is that you should split the logic, and of course changing the direction only when the enemy is outside one of the sides.

Comment: I'm not sure what splitting logic means. Is it what I added to the post?

Comment: @Kewlan Your Edit 2 is what I was thinking about. It doesn't work ? :(

Comment: It does NOT work, and as I said, it's just the same result. Thanks for at least trying to help though!

Comment: You should add the code you use to update enemy's movements, maybe you're doing something wrong there.

Comment: Here you go, it's just as simple as that. If you combine the code I sent you have the main part of the enemy, there's really nothing more to it.